# changing action bar title according to bottom navigation

Tags: android, xml

I created a bottom navigation. Now I want the action bar title to change with the same name as the icon clicked in the bottom navigation.
How can I do it, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding a listener to your bottom navigation view and updating the title of the action bar accordingly?

```
val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            supportActionBar?.title = item.title
            true
}
```